# Javascript running onload instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I need my code to run `onclick` instead of `onload`. I think I have to set `var Delay = to -1;`, but what else? I've seen this code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:initGateway(); return false;">Click here</a>
```

But I have no idea how to use it, or where it goes.

```html
<!-- This goes in the head -->

<style>
A.yourlinkclass {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #CCCCCC;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight:;
}

A.yourlinkclass:hover {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #CCCCCC;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight:;
}
</style>


<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Delay = 10;//Seconds after them clicking the link, the gateway vanishes. 
    function setupgateway()
    {


        var Left = $(window).width() /2;
                Left = Left - $('#gatewaydiv').width()/2;

        var Top = $(window).height() /2;
        Top = Top - $('#gatewaydiv').height()/2;

        $('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');
        $('#gatewayDimmer').width($('html').width());
        $('#gatewayDimmer').height($('html').height());
        $('#gatewayDimmer').css({display:'block', position:'fixed'});
    }

    function removegateway()
    {
        $('#gatewaydiv').css('display', 'none');
        $('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','none');
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.offerlink').click(function()
        {
            setTimeout('removegateway()', Delay*1000);
        });

        setupgateway();
    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">

    body
    {
        background-image:url('http://');
        background-repeat:repeat;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
    }

    #mainContent
    {
        background-color:white;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:130px;
        width:370px;
        border:3px solid #CDCDCD;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #gatewaydiv
    {
        background-image:url("http://");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:370px;
        height:546px;
        padding:px;
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        background-color:;
        border:solid px ;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:tahoma;
    }

    #gatewaydiv h1
    {
        font-size:24px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }

    #gatewayMessage
    {
        font-size:18px;
    }

    .offerlink
    {
        color:#CC9999;
        font-weight:bold;
                font-size:14px;
    }

    #OfferList
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #OfferList
    {
        list-style:none;
    }

    #gatewayDimmer
    {
        background-color:#000000;
        opacity:0.8;
                filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;


    }

</style>




//**this goes in the body**//

<div id="gatewaydimmer">
</div>

<div id="gatewaydiv">
    <ul id="blah">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    <h1></h1>
        <br /><br />
    <li></li>
    </ul>
    <br /><br />

</div>
```

Comment: By the way, you're missing a closing brace for your style declaration. I've added it.

Comment: Please make your code sample more concise.

Comment: Who is going see such a lengthy code?

Comment: concise? uhh... the code brings up a black, partly transparent block that covers and 'locks' the viewing area. and also a message, in another image in the middle. I want that brought up onclick(of a specific image link), not onload

Comment: My bet is that if actually try to make a concise example you'll 'stumble' upon the right solution. It's the best way to learn.

Comment: @Jason Concise means shorter. If you could remove some of the code in your sample so it just shows the problem area, it will be easier to track down the problem.

Comment: only thing i wanna stumble on now is some asperin, lemme tell ya

Comment: what's the point of `Delay = -1`, btw?

Comment: just a guess, i dont know; is there a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, something like this?

```
$('#my-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something here...
});
```

Plus:

```
<a href="http:// ... " id="my-link">Click Me!</a>
```

This way, when you click on the link, instead of getting redirected to somewhere else, the code in `//Do something here...` will be executed.

BTW, you have to wrap it in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
});
```

(or just `$(function(){ ... });`)

in order to have it executed *after* the DOM element for the `<a>` is created.

Comment: where do i put all this? in the head?

Comment: Yeah, usually you should place a `<script>` in `<head>` containing that code.. wrap all your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ .. });` to get it executed once the DOM is fully populated, then use the `.click()` method to add a "onClick" callback to your link (as in the first code example).

Comment: Then, after that, have a serious study of the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/ (!!)